# i want to check that the php string code and html attribute code are equal when the user clicks the button

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function validate5(str)   
        {  
            var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($code);?>

            if (str.valueOf()===myvar.valueOf())  
            {  
              <?php include_once("view/ok.php");
                 $this->model->insertCustomer(); ?>
                 return true;
              }
            else{
                alert("Wrong Key ...Try Again");  
            return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form >
    <h3> Insert Code: </h3> <input type="text"  id="code" />
    <button type="button" onclick="return validate5(code)">Confirm</button>
    </form>
    </body>
```

I've declared the $code correctly
i just want to redirect the user to ok.php if the text user entered matches with the $code is code is correct or stay on same page.
is it possible to it the way i'm trying to do?
if not please suggest some different way

Comment: `var myvar = '<?php echo json_encode($code);?>';`

Comment: Does `$this->model->insertCustomer()` print JS code or are you trying to run PHP code directly from JS? If latter, this can't be done. Use AJAX.

Comment: no it inserts in db...its a function i've declared in model

Comment: <?php echo json_encode($code);?>;

Comment: the above code works fine dont put it in ' '  -Satpal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function validate5()   
    {  
        var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($code);?>
        var str = document.getElementById('code').value;

        if (str==myvar)  
        {  
          window.location.href="/view/ok.php";
             return true;
          }
        else{
            alert("Wrong Key ...Try Again");  
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form >
<h3> Insert Code: </h3> <input type="text"  id="code" />
<button type="button" onclick="return validate5();">Confirm</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.